# Is it possible to skip existing customers already added in QuickBooks database when updating mysql table with Consolibyte/QB PHP integration?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, quickbooks

I am using Consolibyte's PHP/QB integration to insert/update customers to QB on a local machine.

When I initially run the PHP script to insert information from mysql DB to QB,
everything went through--GREAT.

However, when I added a new customer into the mysql DB and ran the consolibyte script again, I received the following error:

Description:
Error message received from application via getLastError(): 3100: The name "John Smith" of the list element is already in use.

I know that I can't insert a duplicate name, but is there a way I can tell the script to skip names that are already in the QB database, instead of aborting the script due to a duplication error?

**According to the documentation, I can pass a unique identifier into QB and make it unique, but my objective is to skip this process as a whole**

http://www.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_error_codes

FUNCTION.PHP

```
function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    /*
        <CustomerRef>
            <ListID>80003579-1231522938</ListID>
        </CustomerRef>  
    */

    $customer = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qb_cust_test WHERE cust_id = " . (int) $ID));

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>'.$customer['f_name'].' '.$customer['l_name'].'</Name>
                        <FirstName>'.$customer['f_name'].'</FirstName>
                        <LastName>'.$customer['l_name'].'</LastName>
                        <Phone>'.$customer['phone'].'</Phone>
                        <Email>'.$customer['email'].'</Email>
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}

/**
 * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
 */
function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE 
            qb_cust_test 
        SET 
            quickbooks_listid = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($idents['ListID']) . "', 
            quickbooks_editsequence = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($idents['EditSequence']) . "'
        WHERE 
            id = " . (int) $ID);
}

//continue if error is 3100
$errmap = array(
        '*' => 'catch_all_errors'
);


function catch_all_errors($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    if ($action == QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER and $errnum == 3100)
    {
        return true; // Ignore this error, all is OK - customer already exists
    }

    // Some other error occurred, stop processing

return false;
```

}

ADD_CUSTOMER.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Require some configuration stuff
 */ 
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
// Queue up the customer add 

// Select all customers first
$customers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qb_cust_test");

while($customer = mysql_fetch_assoc($customers)) {
    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $customer['cust_id']);
}

    die('Customer submitted!');
```

Comment: There are about use the framework for QuickBooks integration. You haven't posted anywhere *near* enough information for us to help you. Post some code. Post what example you started with. Post whether you're using QuickBooks Online or QuickBooks for Windows. Post more information, so that we can help you.

Comment: Hi Keith, I'm glad that you were able to response. I was hoping you would come to my aid. :) I'm editing my post to include the code

Comment: FYI: I'm using QB for windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of the framework/Web Connector is to report errors, and stop the process if an error occurs.

However, you can certainly adjust the default behavior and ignore/handle any errors that come across.

Set up an error handler ([documentation here](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_webconnector#error_handlers_for_traditional_integrations)) to handle the error you're seeing (3100, ...). Make sure that your error handler has `return true;` at the end of it, so that you're returning `true` from the error handler.

Returning `true` tells the Web Connector to continue processing, even if an error/warning occurs. Returning `false` (the default) makes it stop processing.

So you should end up with something like:

```
$errmap = array(
    '*' => 'catch_all_errors' 
);

...

function catch_all_errors($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
    if ($action == QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER and $errnum == 3100)
    {
        return true; // Ignore this error, all is OK - customer already exists
    }

    // Some other error occurred, stop processing 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: SWEEET. So this will just bypass the error? Where do I include this? Underneath the request function?

Comment: Yes. It basically tells it to just ignore that one particular specific error code.

Comment: So I've included in my file after the add customer request function, then I've called the catch all errors function but the web connector is still ceasing.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling the catch all errors function... you should be defining the function, and adding it to your $errmap param. If you're still having trouble, post the updated code.

Comment: This bit: //continue if error is 3100
$errmap = array(
        '*' => 'catch_all_errors'
);   Needs to be the $errmap parameter that gets passed to QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server. You can't just put it any random place in the script - look at your Web Connector endpoint .php script and you'll see that variable defined. Put it there.